# Wordpress Drag n Drop Uploader - Single File Only

Tags: uploads

I have a system in place to allow users to upload files, once they have done this they are thrown into a plugin to allow them to perform various cropping (on the main image and the configured thumbnails).

My problem is that if I upload multiple files it causes issues as the user can only work on one file at a time.

Is there anyway that I can restrict the drag and drop uploader to only accept one file upload at a time? I know that there is the option of the old HTML uploader which does one at a time, but I would prefer to retain the drag and drop option.

Thx

Richard

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hard without understanding how you are arriving to a plugin for editing, but perhaps the user should have the option to choose which file they wish to edit instead of this automatically happening. Similar to how you "choose" which image you want to use as a featured image, for example. This way multiple files can come in, but then they are edited separately. Is there a way to add an "edit" link to the gallery dialogue I wonder?